# get tree structure data from mysql

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql,
problem is , i have a group id like '101'  and i want to get all device id's  which is  under his account and also those id's which are under its sub groups
for eg: if group id is 101: then
device_id should be
    1. 44444
    2. 33333
    3. 55555

```
Table : Groups        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    group_id          |      parent_id          |          group_name
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    101               |      null               |         matrix
    102               |      101                |         sub_matrix1
    103               |      101                |         sub_matrix2
    104               |      null               |         abc        
    105               |      104                |         sub_abc
    106               |      null               |         mega
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Table : Devices
         --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    device_id           |    group_id            |          device_name 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    44444               |      101               |         m1
    33333               |      101               |         m1
    22222               |      102               |         m1
    55555               |      103               |         m1        
    88888               |      104               |         m1
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article about hierarchical data in mysql: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Something like this might work;

```
SELECT t1.device_name
FROM devices AS t1
INNER JOIN groups AS t2 ON t2.group_id = t1.group_id
WHERE t1.group_id = '101' OR t2.parent_id = '101';
```